# IF statement. Variables

Tags: c

I am trying to implement an **IF STATEMENT**
in my **C-Server**.

```
read(client_fd,received_data,100);
printf("%s",received_data);
```

I want to print "**ooo**" if the received data equals to "**test**"

```
if (received_data == "test") {
printf('ooo');
}
```

?

The above example results in errors. (can't compile)

I don't know much C.

**UPDATE :**

Now I can compile fine ( after changing **'ooo'** to **"ooo"** )
But although I am sending "test" to it.. if statement is not doing anything i think.

Comment: Multiple problems.. Strings in C have to be inside double quotes, characters are inside single quotes. You cannot compare strings using `==`, use `strcmp()`

Comment: "results in errors" — And what does the error message say?

Comment: @Haris, using double quotes fixed compile errors. I sent "**test**" to it but if statement is not being triggered I think. I tried "**=**" instead of "**==**" .. compile errors.

Comment: @Joey, use `strcmp()`. In case of strings `=` or `==` will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `==` doesn't work for `const char *`.
Use [**strcmp**](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm) instead.

Comment: how do you use it ? **if (received_data strcmp "test")** ?

Comment: The answer sounds a bit misleading to me. `==` does work for `const char *`, but not in a way OP thinks it does...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I don't get that comment

Comment: @PiotrKamoda Sorry, that was a typo. Edited. Do you get it now?

Comment: Right, I didn't go into too much detail with that xD Let's say it's a simplification.